# String concatenation in Python with "r" prefix and linebreak in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, latex, concatenation

I want to write some text on a matplotlib axis. This text contains a linebreak and should be accessible to LaTex text-rendering.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

mpl.rc('font', family='sans-serif')
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)

fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

text = (r"This is the first line"
         "\n"
         r"And here comes the second one")

ax.text(0.2,0.5,text)
```

produces the following output:

[image]

Now I want to plug the two sentences together such that I am flexible regarding the different inputs of the complete text. I was thinking about somethin like

```
text_1 = "This is the first line"
text_2 = "And here comes the second one"

completeText = [text_1, text_2]

textIn = '⧹n'.join(map(str, completeText))

ax.text(0.2,0.5,textIn)
```

However, this produces the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u29f9' in position 300: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Additionally, is it possible to put a bullet point like in LaTex `itemize` in front of every new line?

Answer (score 2):

Check your `'\n'`,make sure it's not `'⧹n'`.

I used `'\n'` to replace `'⧹n'` in your code.And the code was running successfully.

The difference is that `\`

About the bullet,try this,it work on my ipython notebook.

```
%matplotlib inline    # this line is for my ipython notebook,you don't need it

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

mpl.rc('font', family='sans-serif')
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)

fig = mpl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

text_1 = r"{\bullet}This is the first line"
text_2 = r"{\bullet}And here comes the second one"

completeText = [text_1, text_2]

textIn = '\n'.join(map(str, completeText))

ax.text(0.2,0.5,textIn)


fig.show()
```

Comment: You now, there are days when I just need to put on my glasses before starting to work... Thanks though.

Comment: @Pat Add a `{\bullet}` in front of the line may be helpful.And don't forget the `r` before the whole line.I have improved my answer.